# What possible combinations are there for hexapods?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, evolution

On Earth, life took on a quadruped body plan which has lead to many different sub body plans; 4 legged, 2 legs-2 wings, 2 legs-2 arms, etc. This has made me wonder what possible sub body plans can exist on hexapods. Ignoring tails, what are the possible ways a hexapods limbs can be arranged?

Comment: are these creatures radially symmetrical or bi-lateral? or even tri-lateral?

Comment: @TunaDragon As they are aliens, I'm going to say that they could be any of the three

Comment: I might point out all bugs, snakes, and a moa bird. Just because not _everything_ is a quadruped.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon And starfish. They might not be hexapod, but you can certainly imagine them being so fairly easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Wings**, I suppose, only work in pairs, so they must be an even number (and imply bilateral symmetry): 2, 4, or 6, or, of course, none.

**Legs** seem to be necessarily more than one, or none.

**Arms** could be any number, from 0 to 6, though 5 would be weird, as wings need to be in even numbers, and legs need to be more than one.

**Fins** could be in any number, but their relation to symmetry is interesting; I suppose they could be radially distributed in a perpendicular plan to an otherwise bilateral organism.

So, ignoring other possible - or impossible, but interesting - kinds of members...

- 6 wings disposed in three pairs - weird creature that only flies. I doubt this could be a predator, unless it has a bucal apparatus like those of ants.
- 4 wings and two legs - bilateral creature with as many legs as a bird, and as many wings as an insect.
- 2 wings and 4 legs - Pegasus!
- 4 wings and 2 arms - they must fly to move, or crawl on their arms. But then are their arms really arms?
- 2 wings and 4 arms - same as above. Somehow, I feel that with time two of these arms would evolve into legs unless they live in places with extremely irregular relief.
- 4 wings and 2 fins - similar to some flying fish?
- 2 wings and 4 fins - another kind of flying acquatic animal.
- 6 legs - could have either a radial or a bilateral distribution (like a wingless insect, *Lepisma* for instance).
- 5 legs and 1 arm - like a starfish with an arm at its centre...
- 4 legs and 2 arms - Centauri!
- 3 legs and 3 arms - another radial monster.
- 2 legs and 4 arms - I think some creatures in the movie *Men in Black* are like this. Also, similar to some Hindu gods, though with less arms.
- 6 arms - a fixed animal, perhaps, like some sea anemones with hands at the end of their tentacles. Or maybe like an octopus with two tentacles less - but are they still arms if their primary use is locomotion?
- 5 arms and 1 fin - a radial creature, probably a seagoing predator.
- 4 arms and 2 fins - like a dolphin with arms? Or mermaids with extra arms?
- 3 arms and 3 fins - a quite weird radial critter.
- 2 arms and 4 fins - Mermaids? Fins could be distributed either bilaterally or radially.
- 1 arm and 5 fins - perhaps like an anglerfish with an actual arm instead of an illicium?
- 6 fins - very much like a dolphin with two extra fins. Or could be like some creatures in Escher etchings, also with two more fins.
- 2 wings, 2 legs, 2 arms - Angels, for instance.
- 2 wings, 3 legs, 1 arm - a small change, and they don't like angels at all anymore.
- 2 wings, 3 legs, 1 fin - not sure that such critter would be able to either fly, walk, or swim.
- 2 wings, 2 legs, 2 fins - winged tadpoles?
- 4 wings, 1 arm, 1 fin - again, not sure this could function.
- 4 legs, 1 arm, 1 fin - like a starfish with an arm and a fin, and a leg less?
- 2 legs, 2 arms, 2 fins - Mermaids with legs?
- 2 legs, 3 arms, 1 fin - another monster I have trouble visualising.
- 3 legs, 2 arms, 1 fin - I shouldn't be writing this at night, it might give me nightmares.
- 3 legs, 1 arm, 2 fins - and this is hardly better... I can only hope they don't have mouths like those of lampreys.

  and finally,
- 2 wings, 2 legs, 1 arm, 1 fin - I wonder what environment would have produced this kind of thing. Semi-submersed forests, perhaps?

Comment: Beautifully done! +1

Comment: why do you need more than one leg? hopping around on one thick leg might well be doable... ;)

Comment: @Syndic - but then it would not be a leg, it would be a hopper. And as such, it would fall into the "possible, or impossible but interesting, kinds of members" category...

Comment: Many creatures, such as bats and pterosaurs, use their wings as legs

Answer (score 7):

The number of paired-limb [bilaterally symmetric] plans for hexapods will depend upon how many types of limbs one allows for; radially symmetric plans require a single limb type (otherwise, they would necessarily not be radially symmetric). Given that we're considering hexapods' hypothetical configurations, a trilateral symmetry would probably be in keeping as well.

If we assume only the constraints of your example set of {leg, wing, arm}, then the resulting possible combinations are:

- 3 [radially symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_biology#Radial_symmetry) configurations -- legs x6, arms x6 [I would presume tentacles, here], wings x6;
- 7 unique-counts of [bilaterally symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_biology#Bilateral_symmetry) [**combinations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) (not including the radially symmetric configurations, which technically qualify as any higher order of body symmetry) -- short-handed here as {a, l, w} for brevity yields {lla, llw, aal, aaw, wwa, wwl, alw};
- 24 [**permutations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) possible, of the above-named *combinations* -- {arms, legs, wings} short-handed here as {a, l, w} for brevity yields 
  {aal, aaw, all, ala, alw, awa, awl, aww, laa, lal, law, lla, llw, lwa, lwl, lww, waa, wal, waw, wll, wla, wlw, wwa, wwl}, which gives us 18 sets of two-same/one-different and 6 sets of three-different-pairs;
- 3 [trilaterally symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry#n-fold_rotational_symmetry) configurations, wherein the hexapods have triplets of limbs (rather than pairs), would yield alternating pairs of opposites {alalal, awawaw, lwlwlw}, not including a pair of triplets being equivalent to a bilaterally symmetric configuration (e.g.: lllwww).

Comment: i knew I'd regret commenting instead of answering, +1 from me

Comment: (Thank you for +1.) I saw your comment to O.P. just now, so if it's any consolation, I didn't crib notes from it. (Unfortunately, that might make it worse, since means that there might have been time enough to get in an answer of that sort before mine.)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you 'cribbed notes', I was just saying we had the same idea. It's all good.

Comment: No problem; my bad on the phrasing there. I hadn't thought that that was your inference, much less implication -- I had meant only to assuage possible doubts. (I'm fumbling this badly, sorry.)

Comment: all is well then, good luck with the answer

Comment: They could have 5 legs radially distributed, and a *maist* in the centre. Wait, what is a maist? Well, it is an alien concept, but the explanation, though wonderfully elegant, is too long for a mere comment...

Answer (score 2):

Two on each axis around a sphere.

One on each face of a cube.

Rather than different *function* but arranged in a line, they are facing or working in different *directions*.

Answer (score 1):

The configurations that come to mind are:

1. 2 each for the various functions - locomotion (legs), dexterity (hands/arms), flight (wings).
2. Radial - like a six side start fish.
3. 3 legs, (like a tripod) and 3 arms/hands.
4. Modification of #1: 2 each for the various functions - locomotion (legs), dexterity (hands/arms), 2 for grosser function like lifting heavy weights.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these aliens are more-or-less like vertebrates, then there are around 150 combinations:

- arm, arm, leg: A 4-armed humanoid
- arm, arm, fin: A 4-armed creature like a swimming crab
- arm, arm, prehensile foot: A 4-armed ape-like creature
- arm, arm, prehensile fin: A 6-armed creature like a swimming crab
- arm, arm, flipper-leg: A 4-armed mermaid-like creature
- arm, leg, leg: A centaur
- arm, leg, prehensile foot: An ape-like centaur
- arm, leg, flipper-leg: A mermaid-like centaur
- arm, wing, leg: A winged humanoid
- arm, wing, fin: A flying creature like a swimming crab
- arm, wing, prehensile foot: A winged ape-like creature
- arm, wing, prehensile fin: An aquiline creature like a swimming crab
- arm, wing, flipper-leg: A winged mermaid-like creature
- arm, fin, fin: A mermaid
- arm, fin, flipper-leg: A mermaid with legs
- arm, prehensile foot, prehensile foot: Another ape-like centaur
- arm, prehensile foot, flipper-leg: An ape-like aquatic centaur
- arm, prehensile wing, leg: A 4-armed winged humanoid
- arm, prehensile wing, fin: A 4-armed winged creature like a swimming crab
- arm, prehensile wing, prehensile foot: Another winged ape-like creature
- arm, prehensile wing, prehensile fin: A 6-armed flying creature like a swimming crab
- arm, prehensile wing, flipper-leg: An amphibous winged humanoid
- arm, prehensile fin, prehensile fin: A sea-turtle centaur
- arm, wing-leg, leg: A bat centaur
- arm, wing-leg, prehensile foot: An ape-bat centaur
- arm, wing-leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious bat-centaur
- arm, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: Another sea-turtle centaur
- arm, flipper-wing, fin: A flying sea-turtle centaur
- arm, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: Another amphibious bat-centaur
- leg, leg, leg: An insectoid
- leg, leg, prehensile foot: An eagle-footed insectoid
- leg, leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious insectoid
- leg, wing, leg: A dragon
- leg, wing, prehensile foot: An eagle-footed dragon
- leg, wing, flipper-leg: An amphibious dragon
- leg, fin, flipper-leg: A sea-dragon
- leg, wing-leg, leg: A more realistic dragon
- leg, wing-leg, prehensile foot: A realistic eagle-footed dragon
- leg, wing-leg, flipper-leg: A realistic amphibious dragon
- leg, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: Another amphibious insectoid
- leg, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: Another amphibious dragon
- wing, leg, leg: An avian quadruped
- wing, leg, prehensile foot: An aquiline quadruped
- wing, leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious avian quadruped
- wing, wing, leg: A 4-winged avian creature
- wing, wing, fin: A fully aquatic 4-winged duck-like creature
- wing, wing, prehensile foot: A 4-winged aquiline creature
- wing, wing, prehensile fin: A 4-winged aquiline duck-like creature
- wing, wing, wing-leg: A 6-winged tetrapteryx
- wing, wing, flipper-leg: An amphibious 4-winged avian creature
- wing, wing, flipper-wing: A duck-like tetrapteryx
- wing, fin, fin: A fully-aquatic duck-like quadruped
- wing, fin, prehensile fin: A fully-aquatic aquiline duck-like quadruped
- wing, fin, flipper-leg: A duck-like humanoid
- wing, wing-leg, wing-leg: A 6-winged avian quadruped
- wing, wing-leg, flipper-leg: A 4-winged amphibious avian quadruped
- wing, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: A duck-like quadruped
- wing, flipper-wing, flipper-wing: A flying fish
- fin, fin, fin: A 6-finned fish
- fin, fin, prehensile fin: An aquiline 6-finned fish
- fin, fin, flipper-leg: A 6-finned humanoid fish
- fin, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: An avian quadrupedal fish
- fin, flipper-wing, fin: Another flying fish
- fin, flipper-wing, prehensile fin: An aquiline flying fish
- fin, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: A winged humanoid fish
- prehensile foot, leg, leg: An onocentaur
- prehensile foot, leg, prehensile foot: An ape-like onocentaur
- prehensile foot, leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious onocentaur
- prehensile foot, wing, leg: Another dragon
- prehensile foot, wing, prehensile foot: An ape-like dragon
- prehensile foot, wing, flipper-leg: Another amphibious dragon
- prehensile foot, fin, flipper-leg: Another sea-dragon
- prehensile foot, prehensile foot, leg: A hexapedal ape-like creature
- prehensile foot, prehensile foot, prehensile foot: Another hexapedal ape-like creature
- prehensile foot, prehensile foot, flipper-leg: An amphibious ape-like creature
- prehensile foot, prehensile wing, leg: A 4-armed dragon
- prehensile foot, prehensile wing, prehensile foot: A 6-armed dragon
- prehensile foot, prehensile wing, flipper-leg: A 4-armed amphibious dragon
- prehensile foot, wing-leg, leg: Another more realistic dragon
- prehensile foot, wing-leg, prehensile foot: An ape-like realistic dragon
- prehensile foot, wing-leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious realistic dragon
- prehensile foot, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: A sea-turtle onocentaur
- prehensile foot, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: A flying sea-turtle onocentaur
- prehensile wing, arm, leg: Another 4-armed winged humanoid
- prehensile wing, arm, fin: A 4-armed winged creature like a swimming crab
- prehensile wing, arm, prehensile foot: A 4-armed winged ape-like creature
- prehensile wing, arm, prehensile fin: A 4-armed aquiline creature like a swimming crab
- prehensile wing, arm, flipper-leg: An amphibious 4-armed winged humanoid
- prehensile wing, leg, leg: An avian quadruped with hands
- prehensile wing, leg, prehensile foot: An aquiline quadruped with hands
- prehensile wing, leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious avian quadruped with hands
- prehensile wing, wing, leg: A 4-winged avian creature with hands.
- prehensile wing, wing, fin: A fully aquatic 4-winged duck-like creature with hands
- prehensile wing, wing, wing-leg: A 6-winged tetrapteryx with hands
- prehensile wing, wing, flipper-leg: An 4-winged amphibious avian creature with hands
- prehensile wing, wing, flipper-wing: A duck-like tetrapteryx with hands
- prehensile wing, fin, fin: A fully aquatic duck-like quadruped with hands
- prehensile wing, fin, flipper-leg: A duck-like humanoid with hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile foot, leg: An ape-like avian quadruped
- prehensile wing, prehensile foot, prehensile foot: Another ape-like avian quadruped
- prehensile wing, prehensile foot, flipper-leg: An ape-like amphibious avian quadruped
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, leg: A 4-winged avian creature with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, fin: A fully aquatic 4-winged duck-like creature with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, prehensile foot: A 4-winged aquiline creature with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, prehensile fin: A fully aquatic 4-winged aquiline duck-like creature with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, wing-leg: A 6-winged tetrapteryx with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, flipper-leg: An amphibious avian creature with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile wing, flipper-wing: A duck-like tetrapteryx with 4 hands
- prehensile wing, prehensile fin, prehensile fin: A 6-armed flying fish
- prehensile wing, wing-leg, leg: A 4-winged dragon with arms
- prehensile wing, wing-leg, wing-leg: A 6-winged dragon with arms
- prehensile wing, wing-leg, flipper-leg: A 4-winged amphibious dragon with arms
- prehensile wing, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: A sea-dragon with arms
- prehensile wing, flipper-wing, flipper-wing: A flying fish with arms
- prehensile fin, fin, fin: A 6-finned fish with arms
- prehensile fin, fin, prehensile fin: A 6-finned aquiline fish with arms
- prehensile fin, fin, flipper-leg: A humanoid fish
- prehensile fin, prehensile fin, fin: A 4-armed fish
- prehensile fin, prehensile fin, prehensile fin: A 6-armed fish
- prehensile fin, prehensile fin, flipper-leg: A 4-armed humanoid fish
- prehensile fin, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: An ichthyocentaur
- prehensile fin, flipper-wing, fin: Another flying fish with arms
- prehensile fin, flipper-wing, prehensile fin: An aquiline flying fish with arms
- prehensile fin, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: Another winged humanoid fish
- wing-leg, leg, leg: A 6-legged bat-like creature
- wing-leg, leg, prehensile foot: An aquiline 6-legged bat-like creature
- wing-leg, leg, flipper-leg: An 6-legged amphibious bat-like creature
- wing-leg, fin, flipper-leg: An aquatic bat-like creature
- wing-leg, wing-leg, leg: A 4-winged bat-like creature
- wing-leg, wing-leg, prehensile foot: A 4-winged aquiline bat-like creature
- wing-leg, wing-leg, wing-leg: A 6-winged bat-like creature
- wing-leg, wing-leg, flipper-leg: An amphibious 4-winged bat-like creature
- wing-leg, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: Another amphibious 4-winged bat-like creature
- flipper-leg, fin, flipper-leg: Another sea-dragon
- flipper-leg, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: An aquatic insectoid
- flipper-leg, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: Another sea-dragon
- flipper-wing, fin, fin: Another flying fish
- flipper-wing, fin, prehensile fin: Another aquiline flying fish
- flipper-wing, fin, flipper-leg: Another winged humanoid fish
- flipper-wing, flipper-leg, flipper-leg: An avian quadruped fish
- flipper-wing, flipper-wing, fin: Another flying fish
- flipper-wing, flipper-wing, prehensile fin: Another aquiline flying fish
- flipper-wing, flipper-wing, flipper-leg: Another flying fish